# how to post datas to view cant post data i got an error like undefined variable

Tags: php, post, view

How to post datas to view can't post data i got an error like undefined variable...
This is my view... i got an error `$nk` undefined variable.. how to post data to view?

```
    <div class="messages">
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($nk as $msgs){
    //                    print_r($msg);
    //                    exit;
                        if($msgs['sender'] == '9789445528')
                        {
                    ?>
                    <li class="sent">

                        <p><?php echo $msgs['message'];?></p>
                    </li>
                    <?php }
                    else {?>
                    <li class="replies">

                        <p><?php echo $msgs['message'];?></p>
                    </li>
                    <?php }}?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

This is my controller.....

```
public function index()
    {

        $this->load->model('chat_model');
        $data['ans']=$this->chat_model->chat_list();
//        $this->msg();
//        print_r($data);
//        exit;
        $this->load->view('chat_view',$data);
    }
    public function msg()
    {
        $receiver=$this->input->post('mobile');
        $sender='9789445528';
        $this->load->model('chat_model','nav');
        $data2['nk']=$this->nav->msg($receiver,$sender);
        print_r($data2);
        exit;
        $this->load->view('msg_view',$data2);

    }
```

Comment: ?? There is no use of `$nk` in your code, only used as a key in the $data2 array.    If you want the 'nk' value, you should reference it like `$data2['nk']`, never as `$nk`.

Answer (score 0):

You are exiting your script before the view is loaded.
Right here:

```
    print_r($data2);
    exit;
    $this->load->view('msg_view',$data2);
```

Comment: Which method are you calling index or msg?